# PHP : same functionality design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

Hi I am using repository pattern PHP and from the controller or the service I need to call 1 after 1 to different repository function

$lists is a list of list objects that comes from DB. the repository pattern is the sample Repository pattern

like :

```
        $lists = $this->_listRepo->findAllX($this->config["same_config_param"]);
        $arrayToUpdate = $this->someProcess($lists , $statusA);
        $this->updateDBStatus($arrayToUpdate , $statusA);


        $lists = $this->_listRepo->findAllB($this->config["same_config_param"]);
        $arrayToUpdate = $this->someProcess($lists , $statusB);
        $this->updateDBStatus($arrayToUpdate , $statusB);


        $lists = $this->_listRepo->findAnotherCase($this->config["same_config_param"]);
        $arrayToUpdate = $this->someProcess($lists , $statusC);
        $this->updateDBStatus($arrayToUpdate , $statusC);
```

is there a design pattern to handle it differently and nicely?  maybe should I use FACADE?

thanks

Comment: A *function*, into which you simply pass the variables (literally, the things that vary in these snippets) as *parameters*…?

Comment: did not get you could you share an example ?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between those snippets appears to be the method you call and the `$status` variable. Just make a function with parameters out of that:

```
function doThatThing($method, $status) {
    $lists = $this->_listRepo->$method($this->config["same_config_param"]);
    $arrayToUpdate = $this->someProcess($lists, $status);
    $this->updateDBStatus($arrayToUpdate, $status);
}
```

And call it like:

```
$this->doThatThing('findAllX', $statusA);
$this->doThatThing('findAllB', $statusB);
$this->doThatThing('findAnotherCase', $statusC);
```